# Problems with box-shadowing

Tags: css

I am working on a template for a client, he wants a full width header with bottom box shadow (which is fine) and then a fixed width center-aligned wrapper with left/right shadow.

I gave the header a high z-index so that the bottom-edged shadow is over the preceeding content wrapper. I have also then added the left/right edge shadow for the centered wrapper, except at the top of the wrapper, the shadow is not flush with the header, there is a small gap of about 5 pixels.

I have tried to adjust the spread to cover this gap, but then the shadow goes over the header (even though the wrapper has a lower z-index).

```
#pagecontainer {
position: relative;
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 8px 0 6px -6px black, -8px 0 6px -6px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 8px 0 6px -6px black, -8px 0 6px -6px black;
box-shadow: 8px 0 6px -6px black, -8px 0 6px -6px black;
}
```

Site [here](http://tinyurl.com/ptw2mfv)

Answer (score 0):

You know what it was... the header image had a transparent background and I needed to put a background colour of white in! idiot!

Answer (score 0):

Your header has image with transparent background. Hence the problem. Fixing that will help.